# Do you know why my python packages are not loading properly through conda in Spyder?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, conda

Above is my Command Prompt showing that BeautifulSoup4 is listed and installed. However, I can't call the functions from the module.

I have review multiple forums; however, my modules are not loading into Spyder.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as ml
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets
import requests
import beautifulsoup4 as bs
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup4
```

I am receiving a console error saying:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup4(urllib.urlopen(vgm_url))
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-4-c02a58baa378>", line 1, in <module>
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup4(urllib.urlopen(vgm_url))

NameError: name 'bs4' is not defined


  File "C:\Users\gcant\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\Supervised_Machine_Learning.py", line 11, in <module>
    from sklearn import datasets

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnN8X.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually importing `bs4` but `bs4.BeautifulSoup4`. I think your error is due to the fact that you import it as:

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup4`

And not as:

`import bs4`

If you want to use it naming the module (`bs4.BeautifulSoup4(urllib.urlopen(vgm_url))`) you should only import `bs4`.

Comment: I tried the above import bs4, but the python console says, *** ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'. Also, I tried 'Import beautifulsoup4', and same error. I check Anaconda Navigator and beautifulsoup4 is listed as installed.